# jQuery code doesn't work when normally run. But i does with breakpoints activated

Tags: jquery, firebug, breakpoints

I have the following code in my application:

```
$(".deleteproduct").click(function() {
    id = this.id;
    alert("id: " + id);
});
```

If i run my site nothing happens when I click on an element with the class deleteproduct. But when I place breakpoints before line 1,2 and 3 it works like a charm.

The elements with class deleteproduct are loaded through AJAX call right behind $(document).ready(function(). The .click code is underneath it.

This seems really weird to me. It's working if breakpoints in Firebug are used, but not when there are not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are loading your `.deleteproduct` element via Ajax, you might need to define the click function using jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler.

```
$(".deleteproduct").live('click', function(){
    id = this.id;
    alert("id: "+id);
});
```

or put the function above in the Ajax callback.

Comment: That did it. I tried the .bind. But apparently that is something different. Thanks for you're help. This will be marked solved as soon as I may. Howcome everything works with firebug activated?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a race condition to me.
Have you remembered to put that code inside

```
$().ready(function(){
    ....
});
```

That is so that the document has completely loaded before you try to script against the DOM.

Comment: He could shorten it to $(function() {...});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deleteproduct").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert("id: "+id);
    });
});
```